# Alter table in events

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to create some events in MariaDB. The SQL is accepted without problems and according to this:

```
SELECT EVENT_NAME, LAST_EXECUTED FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.events;
```

My event is executed as planned.

However I can't figure out how to check the result of the SQL that was executed. For example, I created an event with some deliberately incorrect sql syntax - like this:

```
CREATE EVENT testevent
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY '0:1' HOUR_MINUTE
    STARTS TIMESTAMP('2017-01-01')
    COMMENT 'run a test event' DO
        SELECT xNow();
```

This sql should obviously fail but there doesn't seem to be anything in the error log to indicate this. I have tried with SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON' but it doesn't help.

Comment: It's in the error log.  `SELECT @@LOG_ERROR;` to identify the path and name of the error log.

Comment: When I select @@LOG_ERROR i get a blank cell back. I guess this is really basic stuff, but how do I enable error logging? :-)

Comment: Hmmm.  Start here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-log.html